# Docker-compose - mongodb could not be authenticated

Tags: linux, mongodb, shell, ubuntu, docker-compose

After installing Docker Toolbox on Windows 10 and starting docker-machine, I run `docker-compose up`, I run into this error:

`The following packages cannot be authenticated
mongodb-org-shell`

The code in the dockerfile:

`RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
 RUN echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2   multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
 RUN apt-get update
 RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-org-shell
 RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-org-tools`

It's using ubuntu trusty as per mongodb docs recommendations. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

What am I missing for this to successfully download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now i've updated the last 2 lines to have `--force-yes` to bypass authentication.

`RUN apt-get install -y --force-yes mongodb-org-shell
 RUN apt-get install -y --force-yes mongodb-org-tools`